# Ember Data and object graphs

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm a completely new to **emberjs** but excited to get in and play around. One thing I'm struggling with is ... can you load a JSON object that has an object graph depth of more than 1. What I mean is is it seems relatively straight forward to set a Model to a series of name/value pairs where the value is a simple type (string, integer, date, etc.) but what if it's an object?

I imagine it *might* be connected to the relationship model but from what I see in the documentation this only allows for a FK->PK relationship and not an inline object. I'm probably doing a terrible job of explaining what I mean so let me give you an example:

Let's assume that I have a REST call at the endpoint of: `http://my.url.com/place/[place_id]` and the GET call returns:

```
{
    place: {
        name: "string",
        desc: "string",
        location: {
            longitude: float,
            latitude: float,
            radius: int
        }
}
```

In the above example I am struggling to understand how to model `location`. Any help on how to extend this would be greatly appreciated:

```
App.Place = DS.Model.extend({
    name: "string",
    desc: "string",
    location: "?????"
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can introduce a new data transform to handle raw JSON.

```
DS.RESTAdapter.registerTransform('raw', {
    deserialize: function(serialized) {
        return serialized;
    },  
    serialize: function(deserialized) {
        return deserialized;
    }   
});
```

Now you cab define your model with `raw` as the data type for `location`.

```
App.Place = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    desc: DS.attr('string'),
    location: DS.attr('raw')
});
```

If your data from the server has the form

```
place: {
    id: 'place',
    name: 'foo',
    desc: 'bar',
    location: {
        longitude: 1,
        latitude: 2,
        radius: 3
    }
}
```

then you can bind to `location.longitude`, etc. in your template. Here is is fleshed out in [a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ahmacleod/5Wmht/).